# Why is Python greater than operand not working?

Tags: python, if-statement, operands

I am creating code for a simple teachers grading system in which you input the numeric grade and it tells you if it is an A, B, C, etc.
I first wanted to put a limit on the numbers you can input, i.e. can't put less than zero or more than one hundred, but it is not working. Can anyone explain why?

```
import time
from time import sleep
grade = 0
maximum = 100
minimum = 0
grade = input("""Insert numeric grade:
""")
time.sleep(1)
if grade > maximum:
    print ("Please enter a valid grade.")
```

Comment: Because `grade` is a string and `maximum` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should fix this line:

```
if int(grade) > maximum:
```

because the result of `input` is a string, not a number, so the wrong comparison is used.

Of course, you could (and should!) also properly check that user has entered an integer value, otherwise there will be a `ValueError`.

```
try:
   if int(grade) > maximum:
      print("enter a value less than maximum")
except ValueError:
   print("enter an integer value")
```